# Как реализовать Drag & Drop для обычного ListView?

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val adapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter<String>(view.context,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, GoalsDayList)

listViewDay.adapter = adapter
```

Это мой ListView. Для него можно как-то реализовать Drag & Drop?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper

Comment: @ValeraKvip вы не совсем поняли) У меня именно ListView)

Comment: Зачем вам ListView? Возможно проще адаптировать код для ReсyclerView, он намного более гибок и не так жрет память.  Конечно гугл уже имеет ответ и на  [ваш вопрос](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2015/01/drag-and-drop-items-between-listview_13.html) , но лучше присмотритесь к ReсyclerView.